# considering sample weight in lightGBM

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

The **sample set** we used for modeling is sampled from a large **whole dataset**. Usually when we use logistic regression for scorecard model, we will consider the change of the ratio of good to bad sample between **sample set** and **whole dataset** as *factor* or *weight*.

I think the factor will affect the split of tree when we use lightGBM if we consider the model to be applied to the **whole dataset**. Like we have a feature called "age". If we don't consider *weight*, it should split on 32, but the *weight* tells that in the **whole dataset** or the population, more sample is below 25, and the split should be 28.

I found two possible way in lightGBM: set *is_unbalance* to False and set *scale_pos_weight* as our *weight*, or set *is_unbalance* to True and pass our *weight* as array to parameter "sample_weight" in fit function.

I don't know which one is valid and can achieve our goal to consider sample weight in lightGBM